# get json data in a model format Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

i have some categories i the back end and i want to get them in a model format..
my model looks like that:

```
export class Category {
name: string;
id : string;
}
```

and in the backEnd looks like that:

```
{
 "name": "cars",
 "id": "5a082ab8cb2b3f6b373e3042"
}
```

here is my Service :

```
import { Category } from '../../core/models/category.model';
@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }


fetchCategory() 
    {
    return this._http.get<Category>(environment.apiPath+"categories");


      }

  }
```

here is my component :

```
import { Category } from '../../core/models/category.model';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-barter-view',
 templateUrl: './barter-view.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./barter-view.component.css'],
 providers:[CategoryService]
})
export class BarterViewComponent implements OnInit {
allCategories :Category ;
constructor(private cact: CategoryService){}
ngOnInit() {
  this.cact.fetchCategory() .subscribe(response=> {
    console.log(response)
    this.allCategories=response 

    }
 );

}
```

Here my output console :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use interface instead for giving a type for your resut:

```
export interface Category {
 name: string;
 id : string;
}
```